# Shopify support for installment payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, api, shopify

I am developing an app with the payment gateway Conekta.

Conekta today supports installment payments.
How can I set the installment payment option so that customers can make their purchases by selecting payments at 3, 6, 9 and 12 months

How can I put that option to be shown on the "checkout" screen?

Has Shopify support for this requirement?

In what part of the Shopify API documentation, can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a Shopify App that is an external payment gateway. You cannot get this to be part of checkout, so you cannot add field for the customer to select 3,6,9 or 12 months.

Shopify, being a hosted platform, offers payment gateways themselves, you cannot add your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use add the Script in /admin/online_store/preferences at Google Analytics card like this
[image]